# MongoDB: Check if 2 variables are alike

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's say I have documents with 2 variables: first_name, last_name.

I need to check every document to see if the last_name value contains the first_name value.

For example, first_name=John and last_name=John_Smith would be a match.

Can it be done from within the MongoDB shell using the LIKE operator? Ideally not case sensitive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not an issue you can do this with the `$where` operator:

```
db.col.find({$where: "this.last_name.match(new RegExp(this.first_name, 'i'))"})
```